# Not able to make request to backend server in ember (error :'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin')

Tags: javascript, ember.js, nginx, cors, django-cors-headers

I have design adapter in ember js which send requests to backend to get the data but getting a error 
`"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access."` in console.

I can solve the problem if I use the following code in nginx config file on my server.The backend is designed using django.

```
if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
```

But I don't want to disturb the tha nginx config.

adapter

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host:"https://example.com/api/",
});
```

How to send the request so that it doesn't show any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to edit your server's config file. Otherwise, you would have to serve the app from the same domain and port as your back-end.

Comment: how to do serve my app from the same domain and port in ember js .I am very new to ember js and javascript things

Answer (score 1):

Configure this using django-cors-headers in your settings.py:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
  'x-requested-with',
  'content-type',
  'accept',
  'origin',
  'authorization',
  'x-csrftoken',
  'cache-control',
  'accept-encoding',
)
```